# Quick way to mutliply a byte with a float or double, interpreting the byte as normal from 0x00-0x7F, and as 255-128 from 0x80-0xFF?

Tags: java, byte

JavaFX's PixelWriter's ByteBuffer interprets bytes in such a manner.
It seems a tad long to write this using an if-statement and converting between data types, but that's my best idea so far.

I'm currently storing each pixel's color in 3 bytes that, when used, output the correct color. But because I'm only ever going to output them after being passed through the function, they may start in whatever format, as long as multiplying them by 1.0 returns the correct color.
All the floats are <= 1.0, and it's not important which way the answer is rounded.

Some examples:
0xFF * 0.5 == 0x40
0x80 * 0.9 == 0x99

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using char as an unsigned 16 bit value in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809009/using-char-as-an-unsigned-16-bit-value-in-java)

Comment: p.s. i'm NOT the downvoter

Comment: It's not quite the same problem though. I don't need neither signed nor unsigned bytes in that sense. Some bitwise operations seem like a nice idea, but I need the value to "jump" from 127 to 255, and then start counting down. (Because 0x7F is 127, but 0x80 is not 128, but 255, and 0xFF is 128.) @AlexShesterov What kind of edits do I need though? I can't possibly think of how I could be clearer without repeating myself.

Comment: You don't need a 'bunch of if-else blocks'. You need either *one* `if`, or else a lookup table.

Comment: Something like `(b & 0x80) != 0 ? 0xff-(b & ~0x80) : b`.

Comment: Does it really interpret `0xFF` as `128` and not `-128`? The word "apparently" isn't very convincing in the post.

Comment: @Kayaman If I were to pass that byte as a color value, and we counted color values from 0-255, then yes, it does. I'll remove the "apparently".

Comment: @Torn I'm still skeptical. Instead of regular unsigned bytes or 2's complement signed bytes, it has its own way of interpreting bits?

Comment: I don’t get your examples. Are you saying 255 * 0.5 == 64 and 128 * 0.9 = 153? I converted what I thought were unsigned hex values to decimal, and I cannot make sense of it.

Comment: As stated in @AlexShesterov’s link, the standard formula for obtaining the unsigned value of a byte is `int myByteValue = 0xff & myByte;`. This works because 0xff is an int (not a byte) and inserts zeros everywhere in front of the last 8 bits, making sure the sign is positive.

Comment: @EJP That worked, if I did the multiplication after converting the unsigned byte into a signed byte, thank you. It's not quite a full solution, but since my problem is solved now, can I somehow accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value you want from `b`:

```
b = (b & 0x80) != 0 ? 0xff-(b & ~0x80) : 0;
```

and then multiply.